# rest api return image from S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, amazon-s3

I am building the service that should that should return the image. The images are stored on S3, as I send a response I want to sign the image data and send the signature as a header so that receiver can validate it. At the moment I am using `pipe` but I am not sure what should be signed in this case, any help is appreciated

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  const s3 = new AWS.S3(AWS_CONFIG);
  const stream = s3.getObject(options).createReadStream();
  res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
  stream.pipe(res);
});
```